# Убрать cast class в generic методе

Tags: java

Как убрать каст класса в методе Save, использую generic и делаю implement интерфейса.

```
public interface TableOperations<T> {
 T save(T obj) throws SQLException;
}

@Override
public Object save(Object obj) throws SQLException {
    Pupil pupil = (Pupil) obj;
    return pupil;
}
```

Comment: @insolor да, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно указать, что ваш класс реализует `TableOperations<Pupil>` (вместо T подставить конкретный класс):

```
public interface TableOperations<T> {
 T save(T obj) throws SQLException;
}
 
public class SomeClass implements TableOperations<Pupil> {
 
    @Override
    public Pupil save(Pupil pupil) throws SQLException {
 
        return pupil;
    }
 
}
```